# Project Types in SilverLight VS2010

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

HI ALL,

Can anyone explain in brief, What are all the various Project Types in SilverLight VS2010

Thanks

Kishh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these blog entries:

1. [Silverlight 4 Project Types part I
   – Silverlight Application](http://stuff.seans.com/2010/03/20/silverlight-4-project-types-part-i-silverlight-application/)
2. [Silverlight 4 Project Types part II
   – Silverlight Navigation
   Application](http://stuff.seans.com/2010/05/07/silverlight-4-project-types-part-ii-%E2%80%93-silverlight-navigation-application/)
3. [Silverlight 4
   Project Types part III – Silverlight
   Class Library](http://stuff.seans.com/2010/06/04/silverlight-4-project-types-part-iii-silverlight-class-library/)